# Dart Tree Node Example

Tags: tree, dart, dartium, dart-webui

I am brand new to dart and starting to build my own web page.  Does anyone have any good examples of a tree structure in dart (similar to smartgwt treenode)?

I would hate to have to build one from scratch if there are already good examples out there.

Thank you very much.

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buckshot UI (A Dart UI framework similar to WPF) has a TreeView component - that might get you started.

Check the demo treeview demo: http://www.buckshotui.org/sandbox/?demo=treeview

And view the source: https://github.com/prujohn/Buckshot/

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for!!!  Thank you.  It seems to still be in the early stages but definitely a great frame work.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if such widget (written in dart) exists but if you find a similar Javascript widget ( it looks like [there are some](http://www.ajaxline.com/best-javascript-tree-widgets) ), you can use it through the [js package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js).